# How to use the critical.css in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, theme, css, magento2.4

I noticed that I have a `critical.css` file configuration in my new Magento 2.4 installation as you can see in this image below.

[image: Magento 2.4 critical css file]

How can I create it in my theme and what's the purpose of this?

Comment: after activating css critical in magento 2.4.6 [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n0Bq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n0Bq.png), and after testing Google Lighthouse I noticed that the CLS of the desktop version (home page, category page and product page) was raised. I don't know the reason, a solution to properly configure the critical css ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All CSS styles loaded from external files are considered as render-blocking. This means that a web page will not be displayed until these files are loaded.

By using ‘CSS critical path’, we deliver minified critical CSS inline in `<head>` and defer all non-critical styles that are loaded asynchronously. Thus we can significantly improve the time to first render our pages.

## How to enable it

You can enable the admin panel as your image or running this command below.

```
bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 1
```

## How to customize it

You can create a `critical.css` in your custom theme as the example below.

```
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/critical.css
```

Reference: [Magento 2.4 DevDocs - CSS critical path](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-critical-path.html)